# Exception on starting up a Spring Data Neo4J 4.0.0 InProcessServer

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I got the following exception when instantiating a new org.springframework.data.neo4j.server.InProcessServer. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.NoQueryEngine cannot be cast to org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.internal.ServerExecutionEngine
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:255) ~[neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.neo4j.harness.internal.InProcessServerControls.start(InProcessServerControls.java:59) ~[neo4j-harness-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.neo4j.harness.internal.InProcessServerBuilder.newServer(InProcessServerBuilder.java:72) ~[neo4j-harness-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.testutil.TestServer.<init>(TestServer.java:25) ~[neo4j-ogm-1.1.0-tests.jar:na]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.NoQueryEngine cannot be cast to org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.internal.ServerExecutionEngine
    at org.neo4j.server.database.CypherExecutor.start(CypherExecutor.java:44) ~[neo4j-server-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
```

Dependencies in my pom are. My application can be found here https://bitbucket.org/pvlastaridis/neo4jhipsternew.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-harness</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `neo4j-ogm` version is really old- can you change that to `1.1.3`?

You also should not need a dependency on `neo4j-io`

Comment: No luck with these changes